# Maximum values to create partition in each table DB2 for LUW 9.7

Tags: database, db2, partition, db2-luw

Can anyone tell my how many Partition can contain one table in DB2 for LUW 9.7.
Now I have one table with 106 partition, each partition contain 5 milion and this range is powered in 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

For Db2-LUW V9.7 the maximum number of data partitions in a range-partitioned single table is  32,767
This is documented in the [SQL and XML limits](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html) page for that Db2 version.